# Can you vertically align the text of a paragraph that also contains a floated image?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
[image: layout]

Given the following markup:

```css
p > img {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quam velit, vulputate eu pharetra nec, mattis ac neque. Duis vulputate commodo lectus, ac blandit elit tincidunt id. Sed rhoncus, tortor sed eleifend tristique, tortor mauris molestie elit, et lacinia ipsum quam nec dui. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio,
</p>
```

**My largest hurdle is that I cannot change this markup.** So, my question revolves around this specific scenario: Is it possible to vertically align the text inside of an element which also contains a floated image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quam velit, vulputate eu pharetra nec, mattis ac neque. Duis vulputate commodo lectus, ac blandit elit tincidunt id. Sed rhoncus, tortor sed eleifend tristique, tortor mauris molestie elit, et lacinia ipsum quam nec dui. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio,
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad -- The current and previous spec of Flexbox cover the browsers I need to support, so I was able to use this solution.

Comment: Great, glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the `flex` method you could change the `position` property on the `img` element and use `padding` and `calc()` for some good text positioning.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7rvy01cc/1/)**

Of course, YMMV depending on whether or not `img` elements will have standard sizing and how long your text will be.

```css
p > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: calc(300px + 1.25em);
  padding-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.
</p>
```